# How to perform nested loops with Django models with multiple 1 to many relationships inside template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am messing around in Django to understand the framework and have a database schema to model golf course data.  I'm trying to put together a simple view to look at the hole information for a particular golf course.  A golf course has 1 or more Tracks which contain 1 or more sets of Tees each of which have 18 holes with various attributes (hole number, par, yardage, etc).  I'd like to format a simple HTML table for all sets of Tees organized by each Track contained in a particular golf course.  ***I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure the loop in the template to format the data in this way.***

**Here are my models:**

```
class GolfCourse(models.Model):
    """
    This class models the Golf Course Table
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Track(models.Model):
    """
    This class models a Track within a golf course
    """
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(GolfCourse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Tees(models.Model):
    """
    This class models a set of Tee markers on a Track
    """
    track_id = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    slope = models.FloatField()


class HoleInfo(models.Model):
    """
    This class models the information for a hole associated with a Tee
    """
    tee_id = models.ForeignKey(Tees, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hole_number = models.SmallIntegerField()
    par = models.SmallIntegerField()
    handicap = models.SmallIntegerField()
    yardage = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

**Here is the query in my view function:**

```
course_data =  HoleInfo.objects.select_related("tee_id__track_id__course_id").filter(tee_id__track_id__course_id=pk)
```

I was able to figure out how to access fields within the related model objects such as the GolfCourse name associated with the HoleInfo objects but the issue I'm struggling with is how to access iterators within the template so that I can have a nested loop for all Tracks, all Tees within a Track and then all 18 HoleInfo objects for each Tee.

**Snippet of my template:**

```
...
<h1>{{ course_detail.tee_id.track_id.course_id.name }}</h1>
{% for track in course_detail.??? %}
    {% for tee in ??? %}
        <-- Format all 18 hole objects associated with this tee object into a table -->
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: Your naming is confusing. `course_data` is actually a collection of `HoleInfo` instances. I don't even know what `course_detail` is. What is `pk` in your view supposed to represent?

Comment: @Selcuk I believe it is `course_data` passed via `context` as `course_detail`. The OP seems to think that via all the related `HoleInfo` instances gotten from the database, it is possible to output all other info from the other models. **This is true**; that is why it was asked.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon is correct, course_detail  is passed in via context dict and is a list of HoleInfo instances. 

Thank you for validating my approach, but do you know how to do it in the template?

Answer (score 0):

in the template to iterate over the fields you need

```
<h1>{{ course_detail.tee_id.track_id.course_id.name }}</h1>
{% for track in course_detail %}
    
    {{ track.tee_id }}
    {{ track.tee_id.name }}
    {{ track.tee_id.track_id.name }}

{% endfor %}
```